# Programmatically remove block from layout

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I want to remove the product_options_wrapper block from the product view page according to the logedin user via frontend router controller.

I know that I can programmatically append a new block but I didn't find a remove function. :-(

Tried sth. like that

```
$this->getLayout()->unsetBlock('product_options_wrapper');

$this->getLayout()->getBlock('product.info')->remove('product_options_wrapper');
```

But nothing works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The OP code should work, if it used the correct block name, which is **product.info.options.wrapper**, as opposed to the block alias.

```
$this->loadLayout();
//e.g. 
if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId() == [id]){
     $this->getLayout()->unsetBlock('product.info.options.wrapper');
}
$this->renderLayout();
```

Answer (score 8):

Inorder to remove a block using its parent block use the code below

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('product.info')->unsetChild('product_options_wrapper');
```

Comment: Doesn'to work for me. :-( Code is executed without any error, but the block is still there.

Comment: @AndreAusB Then something is re-adding the block after you call `unsetChild`.

Comment: Hey Alan, thanks for your answer, maybe this is the reason. Maybe i should explain into more detail what i'm trying to do. At the product details page of a configurable product i want to remove the  wrapper for the attributes because i want to show a table off all associated simple products with the count of items that are in stock. This should only happen to specific customer groups, that can be configured in the admin interface.To edit the layout of the product details page programmatically i have overriden Mage_Catalog_ProductController->_initProductLayout().

Comment: In initProductLayout i call first parent::_initProductLayout($product);

Comment: After that i try to remove the blocks that i don't need.

Answer (score 6):

This should work:

```
    $blockName = 'left'; // Add yours
    $update = Mage::app()->getLayout()->getUpdate();
    $removeInstruction = "<remove name=\"$blockName\"/>";
    $update->addUpdate($removeInstruction);
```

Why? Have a look in the file `Mage_Core_Model_Layout` in the method `generateXml()` the XML is parsed and where a remove is set for a block, the attribute ignore is added to the block. In the method `generateBlocks()` all the blocks which have that attribute are not added.

Comment: It seems that this snippet isn't working. The page is left blank and when debugging execution stops at $this->getLayout()->getBlock('product_options_wrapper')->addAttribute('ignore',true); without any hint. I think that the methode addAttribute is unknown.

Comment: @AndreAusB Yes, sorry, the block does not have that method, the block in the function was actually an xml node, so I refactored the code to have it the right way. I tested it with the left block on the product view page.

Comment: Doesn'to work for me. :-( Code is executed without any error, but the block is still there.

Comment: I'd never tell anyone not to use a solution that works for them — but creating XML Update strings and applying them in PHP is a little silly.  The XML Update language was created to provide a way to update the layout without PHP code.  If you're using PHP it's best to manipulate the blocks directly in the layout object.

Comment: @Alan Storm I. totally agree. However, it seems that you cannot remove a block easily using just PHP. If you Know how to do it, please create another answer

Comment: The answer @Rohit provides is correct.  If it's not working then unset block is being called too soon, or additional Magento PHP code is re-adding the block.

Comment: @Alan Storm I am well aware of unsetChild, but that is not strong enough when a block is reinserted. Mg goal was to create the Xml remove functionality in PHP. That is how I Interpret the question. Would be nice to Know anyhow!

Comment: In case it's been missed, the `$blockName` in this case would need to be **product.info.options.wrapper**