# override price.phtml template file

Tags: magento, templates, overriding

i'm building a custom module and in some cases I want to replace the price block with a custom block in which prices are not showned, but i can't seem to override the block.
I've used the following code in my modules config.xml

```
    <catalog>
      <rewrite>
        <product_price>Namespace_Module_Block_Catalog_Product_Price</product_price>
      </rewrite>
   </catalog>
```

and i created a /product/price.phtml in my modules template directory, but price.phtml does not override the initial catalog/product/price.phtml
How should i override that template file?

Answer (score 1):

Create your own template file and your own block class. Furthermore you have to override the specific IndexController. In there you should then update the layout and replace the original block with your own one.

Removing blocks programmatically:
[Programatically remove block from layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14275333/programatically-remove-block-from-layout/14305059#14305059)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the original block configuration is still in effect and sets the standard price template.

Does your block class set a template explicitly?

```
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->setTemplate('yourmoduledirectory/product/price.phtml ');
}
```

Or did you provide a layout update that sets the new template?