# Magento - Change Theme from ActionController

Tags: magento

Is it possible to change the complete theme inside an action of an ActionController?

Answer (score 0):

Well theoratically yes as Loadlayout is called in controller.

You use remove blocks if needed refer [Programatically remove block from layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14275333/programatically-remove-block-from-layout) and also by using create blocks you can add blocks..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, probably before layout gets rendered.

But better to make it over session + redirect and default

`$mageRunCode` with store code.
`Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);`
at the end of index.php